# Properties of the Lagrangian in a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

Consider the following linear minimisation problem
$$
(1) \quad \min_{x\geq 0} a^\top x,\\
\quad \quad \quad \text{s.t. }B^\top x=c
$$
where

- $x$ is the $p\times 1$ vector of unknowns.
- $a$ is a $p\times 1$ vector of real numbers.
- $B$ is a $p\times k$ matrix of real scalars.
- $c$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of real scalars.
- $p>k$.

Consider the Lagrangian

$$
 L(x,\mu,\nu)= a^\top x+\mu^{\top}\left(B^\top x-c\right)-\nu^{\top}x,
$$

**Question**: consider the set of solutions $(x^*, \mu^*, \nu^*)$. Is it true here that for each $(\mu^*,\nu^*)$, there is **one and only one** $x^*$? Could you offer some intuitive explanations with your answer?

**My thoughts:** I don't know the "analytical" answer. By doing some simulations, it seems to me that the above is true.

Comment: What if $A=B=0$? Did you consider the KKT conditions and see when you have a unique solution?

Comment: Thanks. 1) What is $A$? If you are referring to some "special" case that makes the problem "trivial", then assume that it is ruled out. 2) I have not tried anything analytical because I'm not sure on how to proceed and make it generic for any $a,B$.

Comment: Consider case $a=(1,0),~t=(t_1,t_2)$, then $a^{\text{T}}t=t_1$ totally independent on $t_2$. In this case minimum is any vector $(0,t_2)$ (satisfying the prescribed linear condition, which can be trivial for example).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that you are highlighting that there can be multiple solutions for $t$. But, what about the Lagrange multiplier? That is my question.